# Laravel backpack Translate create button in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How to translate create button in list view in controller?

Cant find solution in docs.

Comment: Share the code and give descriptions about the problems.

Comment: I just wrote, how to translate create button in CRUD list view on controller. Its fresh install Backpack 5 Pro. no extra code.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change your application url, you can do it in the config, via middleware or similar translation method.
If you want to customize the translations backpack currently have, you [can have a look here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-how-to#customize-the-translated-strings-aka-overwrite-the-language-file)

Cheers